# ROS navigation stack on Jetson TK1 or INFORCE 6540

Tags: ros, navigation, jetson-tk1

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, does anyone try ros navigation stack  and SLAM package on Nvidia TK1 or INFORCE 6540. How is the performance?

Cheers,
Rickardo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220668/ros-navigation-stack-on-jetson-tk1-or-inforce-6540/) by [Rickardo Leos](https://answers.ros.org/users/3712/rickardo-leos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-11-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have run ROS Navigation stack on NVIDIA Jetson TK1 and the performance is good for me..But again, it depends on your expectations and what all you want to run on it. Jetson TK1 is a very good SBC and I am very happy with it.

---

Originally posted by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) with karma: 1464 on 2015-11-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1